Twilio - AvailablePhoneNumbers returns 404 for some countries
I'm trying to get the list of available numbers in Spain (ISO code ES) but I get code 20404 (requested resource was not found).
Request
curl -X GET https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<ACC_SID>/AvailablePhoneNumbers/ES.json \
-u '<ACC_SID>:<AUTH_TOKEN>'

Response
{
  "code": 20404,
  "message": "The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/<ACC_SID>/AvailablePhoneNumbers/ES.json was not found",
  "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404",
  "status": 404
}

I thought I was missing something in the request, but simply changing the country to US, does return something:
curl -X GET https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<ACC_SID>/AvailablePhoneNumbers/US.json \
-u '<ACC_SID>:<AUTH_TOKEN>'

Response
{
  "country_code": "US",
  "country": "United States",
  "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/<ACC_SID>/AvailablePhoneNumbers/US.json",
  "beta": false,
  "subresource_uris": {
    "local": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/<ACC_SID>/AvailablePhoneNumbers/US/Local.json",
    "toll_free": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/<ACC_SID>/AvailablePhoneNumbers/US/TollFree.json"
  }
}

Am I missing something?
Is there something I need to enable on my account to be able to search for numbers in Spain?
Are countries like Spain or France unavailable? Is this documented anywhere?
Is 404 the default response when no numbers are available (weird)?
